# Will .map() with an if-condition loop over all indexes in an array? | JS React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have an array called `temperatures` with data from an API call. I want to render part of the data only when certain conditions are met, and the code I have tried to achieve this with can be seen below:

```
tLowNext1Day =  { 
   temperatures.map((temperature, index ) => { 
       if( temperature.time[index] === todaysDate(0)) 
         return (
            <span key={index}>{
              temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°'}
             </span>
           )}
```

What I think this code will do is look at the data in all the indexes and render the data only when the condition is met (in this case it is whether the date in the data is today's date), however, nothing gets rendered.

If my thinking is wrong here (which it seems), what would be a better way to solve the following problem:

- While in the JSX, look at the date in each index in the array, `temperatures`.
- Render the temperature when the time at the index matches the date of interest.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to remove [index] from this: `temperature.time[index] ` so it becomes `temperature.time ===  todaysDate(0) `

Comment: That was it! Now it works as excepted. But what was happening in my code, why did it not work?

Comment: I explained a bit more complete down below, it's long that I need to create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`temperature` inside your loop is already equal to `temperatures[index]` so you don't need to do `temperature[index] anymore.**

And even though you are doing `temperature.time[index]` which doesn't make sense to put that `index` to your `time` variable.

**So your code would need to be:**

```
tLowNext1Day =  
   temperatures.map((temperature, index ) => { 
         return (
            <span key={index}>{
              temperature.time === todaysDate(0) ? 
              temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°' : ""
             }
             </span>
           )
    }
```

**Or even better to be:**

```
tLowNext1Day =  
   temperatures.map((temperature, index ) => {
         if(temperature.time === todaysDate(0))
            return (
               <span key={index}>
               {temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°'}
               </span>
            )
         return null;
    }
```

- **One more note is that you should not use your looping index as rendering keys. That will mess up with React rendering in some cases**

Answer (score 1):

When I see your code I see something that I guess isn't correct.

Your code :

```
tLowNext1Day =  { // <-- what is this for?
   temperatures.map((temperature, index ) => { 
       if( temperature.time[index] === todaysDate(0)) 
         return (
            <span key={index}>{
              temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°'}
             </span>
           )}
```

Maybe you can try this, first filtering your data and loop it to an array :

```
const tLowNext1Day =  
temperatures.filter(temperature => temperature.time === todaysDate(0))
    .map((temperature, index ) => 
        <span key={index}>{temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°'}
        </span>
     )
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have omitted some code and the tLowNext1Day is a reference to some HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
tLowNext1Day =  { 
   temperatures
      .filter(temperature.time[index] === todaysDate(0)
      .map((temperature, index ) => { 
         return (
            <span key={index}>{
                temperature.data.instant.details.air_temperature+'°'}
             </span>
       )}
```

Answer (score 1):

React will skip rendering undefined returns in case condition is not met but will render the span elements when condition is met. You can refer a sample for this: https://jsfiddle.net/qfh39wgj/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const temperatures = [10, 20, 30];
    return temperatures.map((temperature, index) => {
        if (index === 1) {
        return <span key={index}>{temperature}</span>
      }
    })
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Maybe condition to render is not met due to any of the values of temperature are not meeting todaysDate(0). With preliminary look, you are accessing time object in temperature element. Maybe condition should be like this:

`if( temperatures.time[index] === todaysDate(0))`